# Reference request regarding faithfully exact functors between abelian categories

Tags: reference-request, ct.category-theory, abelian-categories, short-exact-sequences

I am looking for a reference for the following result (or any subresult) in any book or notes:

> **Lemma.** Let $F:\mathcal{A}\to\mathcal{B}$ be an exact functor between abelian categories. The following are equivalent:
>
> 1. $F$ reflects exact sequences, i.e., for every sequence $A\to B\to C$ in $\mathcal{A}$ such that $F(A)\to F(B)\to F(C)$ is exact, also $A\to B\to C$ is exact,
> 2. For every complex $A\to B\to C$ in $\mathcal{A}$ such that $F(A)\to F(B)\to F(C)$ is exact, also $A\to B\to C$ is exact,
> 3. $F$ reflects short exact sequences, i.e., for every sequence $A\to B\to C$ in $\mathcal{A}$ such that $0\to F(A)\to F(B)\to F(C)\to 0$ is exact, also $0\to A\to B\to C\to 0$ is exact,
> 4. For every complex $A\to B\to C$ in $\mathcal{A}$ such that $0\to F(A)\to F(B)\to F(C)\to 0$ is exact, also $0\to A\to B\to C\to 0$ is exact,
> 5. $F$ reflects zero objects (i.e., $\operatorname{Ker}F=0$),
> 6. $F$ reflects zero morphisms,
> 7. $F$ is faithful,
> 8. $F$ reflects monomorphisms and epimorphisms, and
> 9. $F$ reflects isomorphisms (i.e., $F$ is conservative).

The name I know for such a functor is a *faithfully exact functor*, but I don't know any books or sources to look for and Google doesn't help. (It's not that I don't know how to prove the result, *because I do*, but rather that I want to cite it and I'm unable to find it anywhere). The most similar thing I found is T. Ishikawa, *[Faithfully exact functors and their applications to projective modules and injective modules](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/nagoya-mathematical-journal/volume-24/issue-none/Faithfully-exact-functors-and-their-applications-to-projective-modules-and/nmj/1118801336.full)*, Theorem 1.1. However, this result is stated only for modules over a ring (one could leverage Mitchell's embedding, but still, there must be an easy direct proof in the literature), and properties 2, 3, 4, 8, and 9 from the lemma above are missing in Ishikawa's Theorem 1.1

Comment: I have been looking for a reference, without any success. I checked Cartan-Eilenberg, Weibel, Freyd's book, and Kashiwara-Schapira. I would encourage you to just write up your own proof and include it as an appendix to your paper. That would be a real service, given how hard it is to find a reference for the result. Also, the following is relevant: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/271373/equivalent-characterizations-of-faithfully-exact-functors-of-abelian-categories

Comment: I also checked Buhler's survey on exact categories, Barr's survey, Jack Kelly's recent writings, the stacks project, and [the rising sea][http://math.stanford.edu/~vakil/216blog/FOAGnov1817public.pdf]. Also, the following is relevant to you: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2179003/does-faithful-additive-functor-between-abelian-categories-reflect-short-exact-se

Comment: I also checked Maclane's book Homology. No luck.

Answer (score 3):

I found a reference that proves some of the subresults in the question. I also left two comments below the question about places I searched that did NOT contain this result. The reference I found was [K. Shimizu. On unimodular finite tensor categories](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1402.3482.pdf). Int Math Res Notices (2016). Of course, this result was known much earlier but it's hard to find a reference.

Lemma 5.1 in the arxiv version covers your (5), (7), and (9). I think the result numbering might be different between the arxiv version and the published version.

Another good reference is Mitchell's book [Theory of Categories](https://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/%7Ev1ranick/papers/mitchell.pdf).
Theorem II.7.1, which he credits to Freyd, shows that (7) implies (8), (6), and (1)-(4). In Proposition II.7.2, he proves that (5) implies (7). In Exercise 9 on page 77 he proves that (1) implies (7).

I am sorry I couldn't find a reference with all the pieces you asked for. I'm amazed that none of the standard references had this result. I encourage you to write up a proof and include it as an appendix to your next paper. That would do a service to the field and also probably give you lots of citations, as is happening with Shimizu.

EDIT: This thread motivated me to [ask a question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/464693/is-freyds-thesis-available-online-anywhere) about how to find Freyd's thesis. And, that [quickly revealed the thesis](https://github.com/CategoryTheoryArchive/archive/blob/main/resources/1960_freyd_functor-theory.pdf). Freyd calls functors that satisfy (6) "embeddings" and his Theorem 9 proves (6) and (1) are equivalent. His Proposition 12 proves (5) is equivalent to those two as well.

Comment: Thank you very much for all the research effort you put into this! I actually have my unpolished proof written in my github fork of the Stacks Project, I was waiting until A. Johan de Jong came back to (github) life so I could pull-request it.