# Is Freyd's thesis available online anywhere?

Tags: reference-request, ct.category-theory

Peter Freyd is a great category theorist. His PhD dissertation, Functor Theory, dates from Princeton in 1960. It's cited as [14] in Mitchell's book [Theory of categories](https://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/%7Ev1ranick/papers/mitchell.pdf). In fact, [Google scholar says it's been cited 44 times.](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?cites=8704858855510315553&as_sdt=5,36&sciodt=0,36&hl=en) Yet, I cannot find a copy of it online. The [nLab links to many theses](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/list+of+theses+in+category+theory) of category theorists from that era, but does not have a link for Freyd's thesis. Does anyone know if it's available online?

Comment: I was in touch with Pam Freyd (Peter's wife) by email last year. She said that somebody had trashed Peter's computer, so he no longer uses them. I'm not going to publish her email address, but those who need it can contact me privately.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

A PDF of Freyd's 1960 thesis [Functor Theory](https://github.com/CategoryTheoryArchive/archive/blob/main/resources/1960_freyd_functor-theory.pdf) is available in the [Category Theory Archive](https://github.com/CategoryTheoryArchive/archive).

Comment: Thanks! I went ahead and updated the nLab to link to that. My first ever nLab edit.

Comment: @David bravo! Not so bad, was it?

Answer (score 8):

It's on ProQuest at this address:  https://www.proquest.com/docview/301870996

Comment: Wow, great! Thanks! I guess I didn't see it because googling "functor theory" is too general. The Princeton library site I found didn't link to proquest.

Comment: Actually, it wasn't Princeton library. It was WorldCat. Strange that they didn't link to ProQuest! And that Google doesn't find ProQuest either. Thanks again for reminding me to search that source. Here's worldcat: https://search.worldcat.org/title/16637395

Comment: I guess the more general point is that a lot of theses are on ProQuest. No, I don't like their business model either.

Comment: Yes, after your answer, I went looking for other MO questions of the form "where can I find X's thesis" and answered one. And, I updated the nLab with several I found on ProQuest. So, thanks again!

Comment: Is there any information available on how much of the money ProQuest makes goes to the authors of the theses? My guess is 0.00%, but I'll be glad to be corrected.

Comment: My thesis is on there. I've received zero, even though it's been cited many times. But, that's also standard for math, right? I don't get money from my papers in JPAA either.

Comment: I know. I find that just as obnoxious. But what to do?

Comment: I mean, I guess you could write books. But, I wrote a book, and make like $200 a year from it. Certainly not enough to be worth the effort. I guess you could turn your research powers to a purpose that rewards with money, but at that point why stay in academia? I think we get plenty of other rewards from doing research, and changing the model to pay authors for access to their papers might do more harm than good. Just my two cents.

Comment: I do write books. In fact, one of them makes almost enough money to pay minimum wage for the time I spent writing it. It's about maths and music. I have no clue why music is more popular than representation theory, but there you go.

Comment: I wonder what would happen to said royalties (and those of several other authors) if UCAS abolished personal statements.  It would be nice to think that students read for interest and pleasure but I have seen enough of them to have become a bit cynical and suspect that they think we think just saying "I like Maths and am good at it" isn't enough...

Comment: I should also say that yours, as the others, are very good books and have a definite place and purpose that helps the wider community and brings forward the next generation. I've got several in the genre on my own shelves!

Comment: Well, if you want to get some money from your JPAA papers and such, what you've gotta do is make a tiktok music/dance/personal-improvement-product video and rope in some influencers and soon you'll be wallowing in cash like [Scrooge McDuck](https://medium.com/the-coffeelicious/swimming-in-my-money-like-scrooge-mcduck-fc2140e78ee).